# html map not working

Tags: html, css, web, dictionary

For a website I am making for my job, I wanted to use mostly CSS coding, but when I saw all the issues involving CSS maps I took the advice of others and stuck with the traditional HTML style of maps. However, the mapping code wont work, the links remain unclickable. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the CSS/HTML combination or not, but my code is as follows for the HTML part:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">
        <img src="http://i74.photobucket.com/albums/i266/nanashiwolf/header.png" width="770" height="100" alt="logo" border="0" usemap="#headermap" />

<map name="#headermap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="156,67,156,83,225,83,225,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="239,67,239,83,309,83,309,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="324,67,324,83,392,83,392,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="403,67,403,83,511,83,511,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="526,67,526,83,588,83,588,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="602,67,602,83,662,83,662,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="675,67,675,83,736,83,736,67" href="links.html" alt="Links" />
</map>
    </div></div>
```

Following that immediately is another open div for the body of the website, and far as I know there are no issues with that. I was thining maybe it was an issue with the menu tag, but this is all I have for menu:

```
#menu {

    float: left;
    width: 767px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is because I've used maps before and they always work, so the only thing I'm thinking of is the CSS is conflicting it somehow. If I'm looking at the wrong CSS though and another tag would be causing the problem I can post that as well.
Right now I'm viewing this in IE (I havent yet downloaded FF but I will), so I dont know if that could also be an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The map `name` parameter shouldn't have a `#` in it:

```
<map name="headermap">
```

It's only necessary in the usemap directive:

```
<img usemap="#headermap">
```

By putting `#` into the map's name, you'd actually have to use `usemap="##headermap"` instead.

Comment: Just fixed it and refreshed the page, but the map still wont work.

Comment: The map also has to be defined BEFORE you use it. When the browser is parsing the image tag, the `<map>` has not yet been found, so it can't link the two together.

Comment: So then should the map name come after the div menu code? I also should have mentioned I'm using XHTML

Comment: No, it has to come before. You've got what boils down to `<img><map>`. It has to be `<map><img>`.

Comment: ok so if I got this right, it should go <map name> and then <img bla bla bla> then <area><area><area> ?

Comment: No. `<map><area><area>etc..</map>` and **THEN** `<img>` the entire map with areas has to be completed BEFORE you refer to the map with a usemap.

Comment: okay, i tried that and it still doesnt work, but thanks for your help anyway. I'm not doubting your abilities, but I feel bad asking so many questions.

Comment: Just noticed that your coordinates are wrong too. For rectangles, you only specify top-left and bottom-right corners. You've got 4 coordinates specified